# Using babel.js instead of browserify to compile to bundle

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, browserify, babeljs

I am starting out with [babel.js](https://babeljs.io/) to make use of JavaScript ES6 features, however I have run in to a problem

I am currently building my app using browserify and reactify with the following command.

```
browserify -t reactify app/main.js -o public/scripts/bundle.js
```

Now I want to use an equivalent command in babel to bundle up my required modules, written in ES6 to a **bundle.js**. This doesn't work, just giving me an ES5 version of the main.js file.

```
babel app/main.js -o public/scripts/bundle.js
```

However I could compile my bundle.js file to an ES6 version with babel, having 2 commands

```
browserify -t reactify app/main.js -o public/scripts/bundle.js
babel app/main.js -o public/scripts/babel.js
```

**Is this the correct way to use babel with browserify? to bundle your modules with browserify and then convert the bundle to ES6?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nope, the correct way is to use babelify.

```
# from
browserify -t reactify app/main.js -o public/scripts/bundle.js
# to
browserify -t babelify app/main.js -o public/scripts/bundle.js
```

Also the reactify/react-tools/jsx-loader/etc. tools from the react team do a subset of what babel does, so you can remove them entirely if you're using babel.